# UserManager.GetUserAsync without tracking changes?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using the following function to check whether the person that wants to access some database record is an owner of this record:

```
public class AccessGuard
{
    public async Task<bool> IsOwnerOrHaveRightsAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationUser claimant, ClaimsPrincipal User)
    {
        ApplicationUser fullUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (claimant.Id == fullUser.Id)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

It works, but as I've noticed: `ApplicationUser` is now added to ChangeTracker. What it means is I cannot call `userManager.GetUserAsync` later in code, because I get this error:

> The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I usually use `.AsNoTracking()` while accessing database records, but there is nothing like that in userManager. How would you solve this?

I am using it in MVC Controller method as follows:

```
if (!await new AccessGuard().IsOwnerOrHaveRightsAsync(_userManager, Post.Author, User))
{
     return Unauthorized();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `.AsNoTracking()` with `await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);`. Alternatively you can do as follows:

```
public class AccessGuard
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AccessGuard(ApplicationDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
       _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
       _context = context;
    }

   public async Task<bool> IsOwnerOrHaveRightsAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationUser claimant, ClaimsPrincipal User)
   {
        var loggedInUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        ApplicationUser fullUser = _context.ApplicationUsers.AsNoTracking()
                                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(au => au.Id == loggedInUserId);
       if (claimant.Id == fullUser.Id)
       {
           return true;
       }

       return false;
   }
}
```

Then you should register `IHttpContextAccessor` in the `Startup` class as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // Or you can also register as follows

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Then to access `AccessGuard` service in your MVC controller method, first register `AccessGuard` in Startup as follows:

```
services.AddScoped<AccessGuard>();
```

Then in your controller method:

```
public  IActionResult Index()
{
     AccessGuard accessGuardService = (AccessGuard) HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(AccessGuard));

    // Now call `accessGuardService` service method here

     return View();
}
```

You can also get `AccessGuard` service as follows:

```
AccessGuard accessGuardService = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<AccessGuard>();
```

and it requires namespace `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I see that you recommend me to use Dependency Injection here. I thought about that before, but when I try o use that method in my code in some of Controllers (like that `await new AccessGuard().IsOwnerOrHaveRightsAsync(_userManager, Post.Author, User)`) Visual Studio says that I need to provide IHttpContextAccessor as a parameter in AccessGuard()

Comment: I've added full code to question details to make it clearer

Comment: @Piotrek Got it! Wait I am telling you  how will  you use this in your MVC controller method.